# Generate keymaps name list in bash

Tags: bash, terminal

Ok, so... I want to generate a file with all available keymap. I could do it for locales using LC_ALL but I don't know how could I do to do this with the keymaps automatically.

With this command I can get the proper keymap name (es.map.gz)

```
find /usr/share/kbd/keymaps -follow -name "*.gz" | sed 's|^.*/||g' | sort
```

but I wonder if there is any way to get that "es.map.gz" is for "Spanish"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

well the clue is in the file name, the es stands for spain, I don't have these files on my Linux but seen it on the net and admit some may not be as straight forward but in most cases country code. http://fonlow.com/zijianhuang/kpa/trancountry.html

You could also get script to gunzip file to tmp folder then run

```
strings es.map|head -100 |grep {for some pattern}
```

you may find more clues when running strings on the map file as for what language country